# Selecting datetime from dataframe where zero changes to not zero?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, slice, zero

I have a piece of code that is indicating night-time in a plot based on datetime format
like this

```
def night(i):
    i.axvspan(pd.Timestamp('2012 7 17 20:30'),pd.Timestamp('2012 7 18 03:30'),alpha=0.08,color='grey')
    i.axvspan(pd.Timestamp('2012 7 18 20:30'),pd.Timestamp('2012 7 19 03:30'),alpha=0.08,color='grey')
    i.axvspan(pd.Timestamp('2012 7 19 20:30'),pd.Timestamp('2012 7 20 03:30'),alpha=0.08,color='grey')
    i.axvspan(pd.Timestamp('2012 7 20 20:30'),pd.Timestamp('2012 7 21 03:30'),alpha=0.08,color='grey')
```

and further on..

Right now i have set the timestamp manually from inspecting my dataframe for sunrise and sundown, but now i want to create a code that can do it automatically as time sunrise and sundown changes over the year.

In my df i have sunrise is indicated where Kdown shift from **0** to **not 0**.

```
datetime                 Kdown
2012-06-01 02:00:00      0.000000
2012-06-01 02:05:00      0.000000
2012-06-01 02:10:00      0.000000
2012-06-01 02:15:00      0.000000
2012-06-01 02:20:00      0.000000
2012-06-01 02:25:00      0.000000
2012-06-01 02:30:00      0.000000
2012-06-01 02:35:00      0.004167
2012-06-01 02:40:00      0.008333
2012-06-01 02:45:00      0.012500
2012-06-01 02:50:00      0.016667
```

For sundown the its the reversed situation where Kdown change from **not 0** to **0**. Thus, I am looking for a solution to select the **datetime** when 0 changes to not zero?

I have searched for solutions online but i have not yet come across anything that seems to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df['Kdown']>0].groupby('datetime').first()
df[df['Kdown']>0].groupby('datetime').last()
```